# Give specific users complete access to anything I own linux

Tags: linux

At work we have groups set up by corporate and specific users are in specific groups. All of my team is in the same group but we still have problem with file/folder access. We commonly run into a problem of someone starting simulations, the data/outputs being written to a directory and before they leave, they forget to chmod the folder. What happens then is that the remainder of the team can view and read anything but cannot make alterations to folders/files. We cannot make new files or edit current ones.

What I am looking for is a way to give my team members access to any folder/file I own. Is there a way to do this outside of creating a group? Could I have a list stored somewhere that allows users `x, y, and z` access to anything owned by `me`? I want this to bypass my team forgetting to chmod the folders.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setfacl -dm "u:myuser:rwX" /path/to/output/dir` to give any number of specific users read/write access to all files created in a certain directory. You can similarly use `g:mygroup:rwX` to give access to a group.

You can put `umask 002` in `/etc/profile` or `~/.bashrc` to make all newly created files group read/writeable by default, or if that's not sufficient, put `umask 000` in a wrapper script around the simulation to make all simulation output world writeable by default (without affecting your other files).

Finally you can kludge it by writing a script named `fixpermissions` that sets permissions correctly based on arbitrary logic, and give users `sudo` access to run this script (and nothing else). If you're not the administrator, the script can instead only change permissions on files you own.

Such a script can be run on demand, immediately after a simulation (via a wrapper script), on login, on logout, or periodically (via cron).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible using SELinux access controls https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux for example or various other alternative ACLs that require a high degree of user sophistication to manage and operate.

However, it would probably be easier just to use groups.

Comment: IT unfortunately will not allow us to make a team specific group. It is very lame.

Comment: Well if they won't let you use groups then my solution probably won't work as SELinux and many of the other alternative capability based or esoteric ACL solutions typically require kernel drivers.  If they won't let you use groups, those kinds of modifications will probably be off the table too.  Best of luck.